# “the given point must have 2 dimensions” when modifying the center of a 3D layout? (iGraph Python)

Tags: python, coordinates, igraph

Really confused on this. My application reads a file into a graph, and then I create a 3D layout for it, and then modifies the center. However when I load in one of my datasets I get this error: “the given point must have 2 dimensions” from the second line:

```html
miscBucketLayout = graphList[0].layout("fr3d")
miscBucketLayout.center(-160,0,0)
```

Totally lost on what could cause this, if anyone could help me out or give me a direction to start on it would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Cross-posted to igraph forum](https://igraph.discourse.group/t/the-given-point-must-have-2-dimensions-when-modifying-the-center-of-a-3d-layout-python/1092)

Comment: Next time please link cross-posts together.

Comment: Apologies! Will do next time